# Why is this old question a duplicate of a newer one?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

This question was posted in 2009:

[What is the best way to submit disabled inputs as part of a JQuery AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849693/6225838)

And was marked in 2016 as a duplicate of another posted in 2011:

[How to make $.serialize() take into account those disabled :input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4748655/6225838)

Is there a purpose on marking the older one (former) as a duplicate of the more recent one (latter)? Is it because it has newer answers?

Comment: Which one has the better answer?

Comment: Google pretty much made that a no-brainer, it directed over three times as many views to the newer Q+A.  Also supported by the voting, the posts in the newer one has ~8x more votes.

Comment: @BDL I'd say the older one has more descriptive and better explained answers.

Comment: @HansPassant Google actually presented me only the older question with these search terms: `disabled inputs submitted ajax`. So I'm not sure if those views/votes count that much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For duplicates, date isn't a really relevant factor.

More important factors are:

- Quality of the question
- Quality of the answers
- How easy it is to find the question

At least, for that last criterium, the later answer has way more views and votes and thus probably is easier to find (with such a large difference, that likely was already true when it got marked).

Comment: Google actually presented me only the older question with these search terms: `disabled inputs submitted ajax`. IMO the older question has more descriptive and better explained answers.