# Provide justification when flagging a post as duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, flags, close-reasons, duplicate-questions

When I'm flagging a question as a duplicate, it would be nice to have a field in which to provide an optional, brief justification of why I'm flagging.

Particularly in the case where the dupe target is a newer question, but better quality than the older question, it would be nice to give a rationale for which should be closed, since the newer one would typically be closed as a duplicate of the older.

Comment: Can't you just leave a comment?

Comment: @Rene yes, but I was not under the impression that the person reviewing the flags would necessarily read through all the comments looking to see if someone might have said something about a rationale for closing.

Comment: @enharmonic moderators May or may not depending on the nature of the flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see need for such feature as existing options seem to work:

- If you need to provide justification of duplicate there is very good chance that it is actually not a duplicate.
- You can always add some information in comments.
- In rare cases when above options are not enough asking for guidance on meta with "specific-question" tag would be appropriate.

Note that example you have "where the dupe target is a newer question" actually does not need any comment - duplicate target need to have an answer and in case of really identical question be better quality, age does not matter for duplicates (see [Why is this old question a duplicate of a newer one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371852/why-is-this-old-question-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-one) and duplicates for reasoning).